# Command to find a string inside a pattern

Tags: text-processing

Contents of log file are

```
Caused by: com.ofss.fc.framework.exception.BusinessException: The memo start date cannot be earlier than the process date.
at com.ofss.fc.domain.party.service.core.CommentService.validateMemos(CommentService.java:474)
at com.ofss.fc.lz.us.appx.party.service.core.ext.RegionalPartyAddressApplicationServiceSpiExt.preUpdatePartyAddress(RegionalPartyAddressApplicationServiceSpiExt.java:43)
at com.ofss.fc.appx.party.service.core.ext.PartyAddressApplicationServiceSpiExtExecutor.preUpdatePartyAddress(PartyAddressApplicationServiceSpiExtExecutor.java:82)
at com.ofss.fc.appx.party.service.core.PartyAddressApplicationServiceSpi.updatePartyAddress(PartyAddressApplicationServiceSpi.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Caused by: com.ofss.fc.framework.exception.BusinessException: The memo start date cannot be earlier than the process date.
at com.ofss.fc.domain.party.service.core.CommentService.validateMemos(TestService.java:474)
at com.ofss.fc.lz.us.appx.party.service.core.ext.RegionalPartyAddressApplicationServiceSpiExt.preUpdatePartyAddress(RegionalPartyAddressApplicationServiceSpiExt.java:43)
at com.ofss.fc.appx.party.service.core.ext.PartyAddressApplicationServiceSpiExtExecutor.preUpdatePartyAddress(PartyAddressApplicationServiceSpiExtExecutor.java:82)
at com.ofss.fc.appx.party.service.core.PartyAddressApplicationServiceSpi.updatePartyAddress(PartyAddressApplicationServiceSpi.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Grepping `Caused` to get the next line

```
bash-4.1$ a=$(awk '/Caused/{getline; print}' testError.log )
bash-4.1$ echo $a
```

Output:

```
com.ofss.fc.domain.party.service.core.CommentService.validateMemos(CommentService.java:474) at com.ofss.fc.domain.party.service.core.CommentService.validateMemos(TestService.java:474)
```

Required a list of all the name of the files inside the ()

Output of list should be:

```
CommentService.java
TestService.java
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/Caused/{
  N
  s/.*\n[^(]*(//
  s/:[^:]*$//
  p
}' <file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `grep`, assumes java file name consisting of only alphabets, numbers and _

```
awk '/Caused/{getline; print}' testError.log | grep -oE '\w+\.java'
```

Using `sed` for general file name

```
awk '/Caused/{getline; print}' testError.log | sed -r 's/.*\((.*):.*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Staying with `awk`

```
awk '/Caused/{getline; match($0, /[^(]*\.java/); 
     if (RSTART)print(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH))}' file
```